# File downloads over HTTPS keep failing no matter what program I use

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, ssl, download

So this is originally started when I attempted to download a file over HTTPS through google chrome. I was unable to do so. Everytime I tried downloading the file, the download would randomly stop working and chrome labelled it as being a "network error" that caused the failure. I thought it was an issue with chrome itself so then I tried downloading the file over edge, same problem, the download would work for a while then sporadically fail due to a "network error" no matter how many times I retried. I then suspected that it was an error with the file host but it wasnt I tried downloading files over HTTPS from other sites and I would get the same error with the exact same issue. This wasnt an issue with just my browser , I had other applications that were installing software and complaining that they were unable to fetch their required remote files due to a network failure, presumably by the same common cause that prevented my from downloading my files over chrome

Ive already tried

- Disabling my firewall and my antivirus
- Restarting my laptop
- Updating chrome and my OS (Windows 10)
- Using a different web browser
- Restarting my router
- Updating and reinstalling my network drivers
- Disabling my *routers* firewall
- Double checking my system time

Im almost certain that the issue is on my end, since I used a separate laptop and it was able to download files over HTTPS fine so it can't be an issue with my network, router or ISP. Its also not an issue on the hosts end since this behaviour of HTTPS downloads failing was occurring for *every other site I tried downloading files from*. Its also not an issue specifically with chrome because edge also had the same issue, and the other background applications were unable to make web requests. Even more puzzling is the fact that other network related applications work fine. I could stream videos perfectly fine without any hiccups, I can browser websites fine, other applications and services I had running which were sending TCP data were also working fine.

Finally, to get a better sense of what exactly was the issue, I wrote a quick python script to attempt a file download over HTTPS since I was hoping the traceback it would provide me would be more informative than what chrome was giving me. This was the traceback I got

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: **DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC**] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2546)
```

I couldnt find much related to DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC specifically with regards to network failures as prevalent as in my case. From what I read about the error it appears to be some sort of malformed data packets that are causing this. Im not exactly sure how some form of client side error on my end could cause this though

Here are some of the certificates from the sites Ive been having issues with as seen from my browsers certificate viewer. Keep in note that these are not the only problematic sites, since the issue occurs on every site.

```
Common Name (CN)    sni.cloudflaressl.com
Organization (O)    Cloudflare, Inc.
Organizational Unit (OU)    <Not Part Of Certificate>
Common Name (CN)    Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3
Organization (O)    Cloudflare, Inc.
Organizational Unit (OU)    <Not Part Of Certificate>
Issued On   Wednesday, May 11, 2022 at 8:00:00 AM
Expires On  Thursday, May 11, 2023 at 7:59:59 AM
SHA-256 Fingerprint 5A 2B 90 E8 07 F1 34 0B CD B7 63 A6 38 E0 E0 07
38 03 8E B2 47 8B A0 23 8B AE 7D 22 F2 B3 BC BE
SHA-1 Fingerprint   70 EF A9 70 7E D1 3E 0C 11 A5 97 2F BA BD 0B EE
5F 4C FC F9
```

```
Common Name (CN)    *.kali.org
Organization (O)    <Not Part Of Certificate>
Organizational Unit (OU)    <Not Part Of Certificate>
Common Name (CN)    E1
Organization (O)    Let's Encrypt
Organizational Unit (OU)    <Not Part Of Certificate>
Issued On   Sunday, October 23, 2022 at 10:58:58 PM
Expires On  Saturday, January 21, 2023 at 10:58:57 PM
SHA-256 Fingerprint 4E 57 03 B7 6A 12 D3 92 65 91 39 9F 08 7C 1A 6B
F3 00 26 DC ED FC E9 9A E2 CA 76 72 BD 31 39 A2
SHA-1 Fingerprint   A6 C9 6F EF 75 F0 D2 4E FB 0D C4 9A EA 3C 75 2A
13 B4 6C 62
```

```
Common Name (CN)    native-instruments.com
Organization (O)    Native Instruments GmbH
Organizational Unit (OU)    <Not Part Of Certificate>
Common Name (CN)    DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
Organization (O)    DigiCert Inc
Organizational Unit (OU)    www.digicert.com
Issued On   Monday, May 30, 2022 at 8:00:00 AM
Expires On  Thursday, June 1, 2023 at 7:59:59 AM
SHA-256 Fingerprint 06 00 9D 6E 7D 56 41 DE 22 A8 14 54 9E B7 5E 88
C5 DB B9 44 29 05 28 9D 7F 70 71 22 A6 DA C9 08
SHA-1 Fingerprint   AA ED F2 98 B7 6C 2D AE F2 77 D2 2A A9 A6 05 C5
B0 A1 0B 1F
```

Comment: Microsoft is rolling out HTTP2, and this might be the cause of it. You can try to start google chrome with --disable-http2 and see if it works then

Comment: @LPChip From the command line I launched chrome with `chrome --disable-http2`. Tried again, same error.

Comment: Have you set your system time correctly?

Comment: @Allman yes. It is exactly what the time is on my other working laptop

Comment: `that caused the failure` .. unlikely.

Comment: `DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC` is an indication that the browser or application was unable to decrypt the encrypted HTTPS connection.  One of the only reasons that would be the case is your using the wrong certificate. If Chrome and Edge show the same problems, since they share the same certificate store, the problem most certainly is with the certificate installed in the certificate store. In order to diagnose this problem you will have to post some information about a single website, specifically, the certificate used for that website.

Comment: @Ramhound I dont have any issues using SSL for any of the websites I am browsing normally, that includes the ones which I am unable to download files from. Chrome and edge are telling me that my certificates are valid. And its not just one site, its almost every site Ive tried and they use different certificates that are all valid.

Comment: @eclipse - So you can’t provide any additional information?

Comment: @Ramhound Ive appended some certificate information to my answer, let me know what else you need

Comment: @Ramhound+ certificates are never used to decrypt data in HTTPS (or other SSL/TLS) and this alert only applies to decrypting packets after CCS which only happens after/if the certificate is successfully validated, so it **cannot be caused by the certificate(s)**. eclipse: this only happens if (data in) a packet is corrupted somewhere (and you've ruled out externally) or there's a bug in the program you use (very unlikely). In the old days I'd start switching components, but now that requires a factory and cleanroom. At minimum check nothing in your machine is overheating or dusty.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - So your explanation for the authors behavior is that there is a TLS bug in Chrome? Certificates not being used to decrypt encrypted data is news to me. I find your claim dubious. It also goes against the message saying there was a decryption error.

Comment: If an HTTPS connection breaks in the middle of a download something may be wrong with the network at al. Or if the used anti virus solution performs network interception may be a bad anti virus system may be the cause. May be disabling anti virus does not include that network scanner?

Comment: @Robert Ive already ruled out AV and the fact that its a network issue. Ive disabled AV and my firewall entirely and also had no issues on other PCs